# Notes becoming Sheimos

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, writing-printing

How coherent does a Torah thought have to be in order to make it Sheimos (not allowed to be disposed of normally)?

Is it enough if:

-It is written shorthand in such a way that only I would be able to reconstruct the train of thought

-It is concise enough that only someone already familiar with the topic would realize what it was saying

-It refers to Torah thoughts but does not explicitly spell any out (ex. a list of related sources)

Answer (score 1):

See http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1587/comment-page-1: (there's more there than I quote here, but I think this is most relevant to the question)

> HOLY BOOKS THAT DO NOT INCLUDE HASHEM’S NAME
>
> Destroying Torah writings that do not include Hashem’s name is prohibited mi’derabbanan (see Rambam, Hil. Yesodei HaTorah 6:8, based on Shabbos 115, 116). Thus, Mishnayos, Gemaras, and most parts of commentaries on Tanach, Gemara, Halacha and Aggadah are considered sheimos only mi’derabbanan since it is unusual to find Hashem’s names in them.
>   Reference notes that are incomprehensible on their own are not considered divrei torah and may be placed in the regular garbage (Shu”t Igros Moshe, Yoreh Deah 2:75).
>
> PRINTED WORKS CONTAINING DIVREI TORAH
>
> Is there any halachic difference between a printed sefer, which has kedusha, and a printed work on a non-holy subject that happens to contain some divrei torah or quotations from Chazal?
>
> THE WRITER’S INTENT
>
> Some halachic authorities maintain that if a printer or writer did not intend to produce seforim or divrei kedusha, then the resultant product has no kedusha (Shu”t Ein Yitzchak 5:7-9; Chazon Ish, Yoreh Deah 164:3 s.v. ve’im; see also Shu”t Igros Moshe, Yoreh Deah 1:172). According to this approach, a book published on a non-Torah subject that includes some divrei torah need not be placed in genizah when it wears out. This lenience applies only to items that do not contain one of the seven names of Hashem (Shu”t Meishiv Davar 2:80).

Later on, in the context of newspapers and magazines:

> HOLY BOOKS THAT DO NOT INCLUDE HASHEM’S NAME
>
> Destroying Torah writings that do not include Hashem’s name is prohibited mi’derabbanan (see Rambam, Hil. Yesodei HaTorah 6:8, based on Shabbos 115, 116). Thus, Mishnayos, Gemaras, and most parts of commentaries on Tanach, Gemara, Halacha and Aggadah are considered sheimos only mi’derabbanan since it is unusual to find Hashem’s names in them.
>   PERMANENCE
>
> Several earlier authorities imply that divrei torah intended to be temporary do not have kedusha (see Shu”t Ayn Yitzchak #5:7; Shu”t Meishiv Davar 2:80). The line of reasoning here is that since the printer does intend to create permanent Torah works, the items do not become holy. This approach explains the common practice of photocopying Torah quotations for one time use without exerting major effort to retrieve the items for genizah. I leave it to the reader to discuss with his rav whether he may follow this approach.